# Show that: if $Cond_2(A)=1$ then $A=\alpha Q$; where $Q $ is an orthonormal matrix and $\alpha$ is a real number $\neq 0$

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices, condition-number

Show that:

if $Cond_2(A)=1$
then $A=\alpha Q$; where $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix and $\alpha$ is a real number$\neq 0$

The condition number is defined as theorem as

$Cond_2(A)=  ||A|| \hspace{0.1cm}||A^{-1}||$

In this case, the operator norm is $L_2$.

The condition number theorem is extracted from the book: Numerical Linear Algebra, Lloyd N. Trefethen, David Bau, First Edition, page 95.

[image]

**My work first idea**

If the condition number is is equal to 1 then

$$||A||=\frac{1}{||A^{-1}||} \Leftrightarrow  |\sigma_{max}|=|\sigma_{min}|$$

Where
$\sigma_{max}$ and $\sigma_{min }$ is the eigenvalue with the biggest and lowest norm respectively.

From here we can conclude that. If the condition number is one then all the eigenvalues have the same norm $|\sigma_{i}|=1$.

**Main problem**

How to conclude from this result that the matrix A has the form of $\alpha Q$

**My work second idea**

Using SVD we obtain that.

$$||Q\Sigma V^*||||(Q\Sigma V^*)^{-1}||=||\Sigma|||\Sigma^{-1}|||= |\sigma_{max}|\frac{1}{|\sigma_{min}|}=1$$

From the last equation, we obtain the same results of **My work first idea**

The norms of all eigenvalues are equal to one.

**General overview**

How to conclude that the structure of A is $A=\alpha Q$

Comment: do you know what SVD is?  The result should be immediate if you know that.  In any case showing some work here would be prudent.

Comment: Just FYI - that is not the "condition number", only an estimate of it. If you were using the operator norm, then it would be the condition number (though by theorem, not definition), But using the $L_2$ norm is not quite the same.

Comment: But at user8675309 points out, this is your problem, not ours. We are willing to help you with it, but not to just solve it for you. Please show what you've attempted and where you are stuck. Otherwise, this post will either attract down votes and be closed, or else just be ignored.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes I agree, I will write the work I have done towards this problem. And extend the question. Just give me some minutes :)

Comment: @user8675309 I have edited the post based on your recommendation, thanks.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have added the theorem you just mentioned to use theorem instead of a definition. On the other hand, what do you mean with "Using the $L_2$ norm is not quiet the same"?

Comment: There are many different norms that you can define on the space of automorphisms of a vector space. The theorem is about the operator norm, which is $$\|A\|_{op} = \sup_v \frac {\|Av\|_V}{\|v\|_V}$$ where $\|\phantom v\|_V$ is the vector space norm. But the $L_2$ norm is $$\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2}$$where the $a_{ij} = \langle e_i, Ae_j\rangle$ for some orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$. These two norms do not always agree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111892/discussion-between-juanmunoz-and-paul-sinclair).

Comment: @user8675309 I have applied the SVD as you mentioned. Nevertheless I can not find a clear path to follow. You mentioned the result follows immediately. Could you please expand your orientation?

Comment: while you haven't specified norm, I assume you have a standard selection where $k(A)=\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_n}$ with usual ordering of singular values  $\sigma_1\geq \sigma_2\geq....\geq \sigma_n$ and we're working over $\mathbb R$.  In your case $k(A) = 1\longrightarrow  \alpha=\sigma_1= \sigma_2= ....=\sigma_n$.  Thus $A=U\Sigma V^T= U(\alpha I)V^T = \alpha UV^T= \alpha Q$

Comment: @user8675309 Nice, it is very clear. My problem came from my confusion between singular values and eigenvalues.